# How to create a node with id 0?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I deleted the reference node. So I need to recreate the reference node.
Using cypher how to create a node with id 0?

thanks.

Comment: Restart the database, the next node you'd create should have id 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't, and you don't need to. Do you have a specific problem without that node? If so, maybe you can elaborate, chances are there is something else that answers your problem better than trying to recreate a node with a specific id.

The long answer is you can't assign id:s to nodes with cypher. The id is an index or offset into the node storage on disk, so it makes sense to let Neo4j worry about it and not try to manipulate it or include it in any application logic. See [Node identifiers in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051442/node-identifiers-in-neo4j) and [Has anyone used Neo4j node IDs as foreign keys to other databases for large property sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527334/has-anyone-used-neo4j-node-ids-as-foreign-keys-to-other-databases-for-large-prop?rq=1).

You also most likely don't need a reference node. It is created by default in a new database, but it's use is deprecated and it won't exist in future releases. See [Is concept of reference node in neo4j still used or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088616/is-concept-of-reference-node-in-neo4j-still-used-or-deprecated).

If you still want to assign id to nodes you create, it is accidentally possible in a roundabout way with with the CSV batch importer ([1](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import),[2](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#import-data-into-your-neo4j-database-from-the-neo4j-shell-command)) and, I believe, with the Java API [batch inserter](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html).

If you still want to recreate or simulate the reference node you can either delete the database data files and let Neo4j recreate the the database, or you can try what this person did: [Recreate reference node in a Neo4j database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186832/recreate-reference-node-in-a-neo4j-database). You can also force Neo4j to recycle the ids of deleted nodes faster, so that new nodes that you create receive those ids that have been freed up and not yet reassigned.